# How to dynamically add data in data() from a v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm collecting questions from my database. I post these questions with v-for. I also create an input for users to answer these questions.

```
        <el-form v-model="answer" class="form-bilan" label-position="top">
            <el-form-item label="test" :label="question.question_without_html"
                                        class="form-bilan__label-input"
                                        :for="'question_' + question.id"
                                        :key="question.id"
                                        v-for="question in questions.questions"
                                        v-if="question.type == 'label-input'">
                <el-input :id="'question_' + question.id"></el-input>
            </el-form-item>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </el-form>
```

I would like to link these input (answers) to an object in data() to be able to send them with axios on my server

Do you have an idea of how?

```
data() {
  return {
    answer: {

            },
    }
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use v-model and bind the answers to a property in data, here a functional example:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: {
      answer: null,
      questions: {
        questions: [
          { id: 1, type: 'label-input'},
          { id: 2, type: 'label-input'},
        ]
      },
      answers: {}
    },
    methods: {
      doClickAnswers () {
        console.clear();
        console.log(this.answers)
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!-- import CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css">
<!-- import JavaScript -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  <el-form
    v-model="answer"
    class="form-bilan"
    label-position="top">
    
    <el-form-item
      label="test"
      style="max-width: 200px;display: inline-block;margin: 0;"
      :label="question.question_without_html"
      :for="'question_' + question.id"
      :key="question.id"
      v-for="question in questions.questions"
      v-if="question.type == 'label-input'">
      
      <el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
      
    </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
    <button type="button" @click="doClickAnswers">answers</button>
</div>
```